# kendo grid selection doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

this is my sample page with a simple kendo grid:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>New</title>
<link href="../styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="../styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="../jQuery/jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="grid"></div>
<script>
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        columns: [
          { field: "name" },
          { field: "age" }
        ],
        dataSource: [
          { name: "Jane Doe", age: 30 },
          { name: "John Doe", age: 33 }
        ],
        selectable: true
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

both with firefox and explorer, the row selection doesn't work....
thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of kendo are you using ?

Answer (score 2):

Try to wrap your code inside DOM ready:

```
$(function() {
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        columns: [
          { field: "name" },
          { field: "age" }
        ],
        dataSource: [
          { name: "Jane Doe", age: 30 },
          { name: "John Doe", age: 33 }
        ],
        selectable: true
    });
});
```

It's to ensure that your function is called once all the DOM elements of the page are ready to be used.

Comment: it's the same thing, not working, it could depend from jquery, because if I include jquery 1.8.0 it works fine both with firefox and explorer, it doesn't work with jquery 2.0.0 and more, but I need to use jquery 2.0.0!!!

Comment: @pasluc74669 Any error in the console? It's maybe because of the incompatibility of kendo grid with jQuery version `2.0.0`.